# Using the Swiper library

Tags: javascript, anchor, swiper.js

Here is my problem, I have to propose 3 ways to anchor:

- anchor on the slide corresponding to today's date (I already have the day);
- force the slide through the URL;
- and force the slide using the query url method.

The code used must be almost identical for the 3 ways of doing it. I have already found the hash navigation method of the library but either it is not that or I do not know how to use it, can you enlighten me? I enclose the initialization of my swiper if it can help you. Thanks !

```
const swiper = new Swiper('.swiper', {  
  direction: 'vertical',
  loop: true,
  navigation: {
    nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
    prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
  },
  on: {
    resize: function () {
      swiper.changeDirection('vertical');
    }
  },
  pagination: {
    el: '.swiper-pagination',
    type: "fraction",
  },
  hashNavigation: {
    watchState: true,
  },
});
```

I specify that I use Swiper with the native version of JavaScript.